# DateTimeIndex should be sorted, but isn't

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resample a DateTime Series in pandas as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pathToParam + "/" + file)
df.drop(["LAT", "LON", "STATION_HEIGHT"], axis = 1, inplace=True)
df.set_index(df.DATE, inplace=True, drop=True)
if granularity == "daily":
     df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, cache=False)
     df = df.sort_index()
     df = df.resample("8H", closed="right").bfill()
```

The Dataframe looks like this:

| DATE | STATION_ID | CLOUD_COVER_TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-01-01 | 1048 | 6.7 |
| 2016-01-02 | 1048 | 7.8 |
| 2016-01-03 | 1048 | 7.8 |

But I always get this error:

```
ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
```

I tried `parse_dates = True` and searched for possible solutions on a variety of platforms, still empty handed. Pls help.

Comment: Some ideas - Do you use last pandas version? Is possible some datetimes are duplicated?

Comment: @jezrael - pandas is at 1.1.4 and there can't be any duplicates

Comment: If test to remove `closed="right"` still error?

Comment: yes, still the same

Comment: cannot simulate, for me working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely one of the rows in your csv has an empty value where the date should be.

I can recreate your problem only if I intentionally put a blank date in:

```
dateSeries = ["2016-01-01", "", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-04"]
data = [[1048, 6.7], [1048, 7.8], [1048, 7.8], [1048,7.8]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = dateSeries, columns=["STATION_ID", "CLOUD_COVER_TOTAL"])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, cache=False)
df = df.sort_index()
df = df.resample("8H", closed="right").bfill()
```

Draws this error

```
ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
```

If I have values in each index it works fine.   You can find such problematic records with things like:

```
df.loc[None]
```

or

```
df.loc[""]
```

or

```
df.loc[pd.NaT]
```

Comment: I actually had a blank date (mysteriously unexpected), thank you for your time sir!